# Access posts while mod_rewrite is broken

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, mod-rewrite

On my wordpress installation mod_rewrite (e.g. the permalinks) is temporarily broken. For debugging I want to access the formerly "prettified" page `mydomain.tld/page/2`. What is the old GET parameter for it?

Answer (score 1):

get parameter for this is `paged`.
Example: `mydomain.tld?paged=2`

Answer (score 0):

The query string format-- the "default" permalink-- should always work. For posts that is `?p=<post-id>` for pages it is `?page=<page-id>`, though `?p=` will also work for pages (with the overhead or a redirect). Categories are `?cat=<cat-id>`. Tags are `?tag=<tag-id>`. There are many others.